# Sum the value of two labels in devexpress xtrareports

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

If there is a way I can get a sum from two labels and show the result in a third label. Right now I've been having problems with the sums in one of my reports and if there's a way I can sum the labels instead of making a calculated field, I think I can solve my problem.

I was investigating in the matter and I found similar questions in the forums, but the response they give didn't solve my question.
Here are the links to the questions:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q316239
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q470883

I'm working the reports in visual studio 2012 using c# and my DevExpress version is the 14.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`XRControl.BeforePrint`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXRControl_BeforePrinttopic) event. In this event you can simply change the text of your label. You can get the text from your other labels:

```
private void xrLabel3_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    xrLabel3.Text = (int.Parse(xrLabel1.Text) + int.Parse(xrLabel2.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Also you can use [`XtraReportBase.GetCurrentColumnValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_GetCurrentColumnValue[T]topic) method to get current values:

```
private void xrLabel3_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    xrLabel3.Text = (GetCurrentColumnValue<int>("FirstValue") + GetCurrentColumnValue<int>("SecondValue")).ToString();
}
```

And you can use [`XtraReportBase.GetCurrentRow`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIXtraReportBase_GetCurrentRowtopic) method to get the underlying data object:

```
private void xrLabel3_BeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
{
    var yourData = (YourDataClass)GetCurrentRow();
    xrLabel3.Text = (yourData.FirstValue + yourData.SecondValue).ToString();
}
```